Computing empirical coverage in binary classification confidence estimation
I am trying to compute confidence interval empirical coverage. I have computed the confidence intervals for binary probability predictions. For example, the model estimates that there is probability of 0.3 that the label is 1, with a confidence interval between 0.23 and 0.33.
To compute the empirical coverage I can't check if this interval contains the target, because the target will always be 0 and 1, and in that sense the CI would always be "wrong". What I need is to have a probability of the label being 1, and check if the established CI contains it.
What I did was: sample 10% of the test data, compute the prevalence (ie. the average number of samples where the label is 1), compute the mean lower and upper bounds and check if the mean bounds contain the prevalence. I then repeat this procedure a large number of times and check the percentage that violated the boundaries. This is a stretched version of calibration if I'm correct. For a CI with 95% nominal coverage, this yielded an empirical coverage of 94.5% which is great. However, if I were to replace the sample fraction with any other number, I no longer obtain this good of an empirical coverage. I repeated the procedure for a 90% CI and observed the exact same behaviour (the empirical coverage was 89%).
What is wrong with this procedure? Or rather, why does the sampled fraction have to be 10%? Is there another way I can validate the established CIs in a binary context?
